# Eisenstein and Weierstrass zeta - series identity

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, modular-forms

Let $\zeta_\Lambda$ be the Weierstrass $\zeta$-function for lattice $\Lambda$ and $G_2$ the Eisenstein series of weight $2$.

The quasiperiod is defined by $\eta_\Lambda(\lambda) := \zeta_\Lambda(z + \lambda) - \zeta_\Lambda(z)$.

Then the following identity holds \begin{align*} \eta_{\Lambda_\tau}(1)=G_2(\tau) .\end{align*}

I tried to check the series definition and i am not sure on how to continue with that 
\begin{align*}
 \zeta_\Lambda(z + 1) - \zeta_\Lambda(z) &= \frac{1}{z+1} + \left( \sum_{(c,d) \neq (0,0)} \frac{1}{(z+1)-(c \tau +d)} +\frac{1}{c \tau +d}+ \frac{z+1}{(c \tau +d)^2}\right) \\ &-\frac{1}{z} + \left( \sum_{(c,d) \neq (0,0)} \frac{1}{z-(c \tau +d)} +\frac{1}{c \tau +d} + \frac{z}{(c \tau +d)^2}\right) \\ &= \left(\frac{1}{z+1} - \frac{1}{z} \right) +... 
\end{align*}

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: @reuns i wrote the series definition of $\zeta_\Lambda$... is it wrong? because i am not sure on how to get $G_2$ with it. I would really appreciate your help on this

Comment: You didn't write $\zeta_\Lambda$ nor $G_2$

Comment: @reuns We defined the $\zeta$ function as 
$\zeta_{\Lambda}(z):= \frac{1}{z} + \sum_{w \in \Lambda \setminus \{0\}} \left(\frac{1} {z-w}+\frac{1}{w} + \frac{z}{w^2}\right)$, so i just let $w = c\tau +d$ and got the above sum for $\zeta_\Lambda(z+1)- \zeta_\Lambda(z)$. Is this wrong?

Comment: And $G_2{}{}{}$ ?

Comment: @reuns We defined it as \begin{align*}G_2(\tau) := \sum_{\substack{(m,n) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \\ (m,n) \neq (0,0)}} \frac{1}{(m \tau +n)^{k}}= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n \neq 0} \frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{m \neq 0} \sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{(m \tau +n)^{2}}.  \end{align*} So i tried to rewrite the $\zeta$ equation into $G_2$ but failed

Comment: @reuns ok i found $$
G_2(\tau)=\sum_{c\in\mathbb{Z}}\sum_{d\in\mathbb{Z} \setminus\{0\}}\frac{1}{(c\tau+d)^2}
$$ but i am really confused now...

Comment: @reuns hmm i dont know any other representation of it so i would be glad if you could lighten me up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$G_2(\tau)=\sum_c\sum_d\frac{1_{(c,d)\ne (0,0)}}{(c\tau+d)^2}$$

It converges and is holomorphic for $\Im(\tau)> 0$ because $\sum_d \frac{1}{(c\tau+d)^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi c\tau)}= O(e^{-2 \pi |c\Im(\tau)|})$. Then $$\zeta_\tau(z) =\sum_c\sum_d\frac{1}{z-c\tau-d}+1_{(c,d)\ne (0,0)}(\frac{1}{c\tau+d}+\frac{z }{(c\tau+d)^2})$$
$$ =\sum_c\sum_d\frac{1}{z-c\tau-d-1}+1_{(c,d+1)\ne (0,0)}(\frac{1}{c\tau+d+1}+\frac{z }{(c\tau+d+1)^2})$$

From there the result is immediate

$$\zeta_\tau(z+1)-\zeta_\tau(z)-G_2(\tau)\\=\sum_c\sum_d 1_{(c,d)\ne (0,0)}(\frac{1}{c\tau+d}+\frac{z+1}{(c\tau+d)^2})-1_{(c,d+1)\ne (0,0)}(\frac{1}{c\tau+d+1}+\frac{z}{(c\tau+d+1)^2})-\frac{1_{(c,d)\ne (0,0)}}{(c\tau+d)^2}\\=0$$

Comment: thank you alot. I have a question though. What does the numerator in $$G_2(\tau)=\sum_c\sum_d\frac{1_{(c,d)\ne (0,0)}}{(c\tau+d)^2}$$ mean?

Comment: $1$ if $(c,d) \ne (0,0)$, $\quad 0$ otherwise

Comment: @reuns i was confused first but your last edit fixed all. thanks alot again