# Weierstrass Zeta function Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Let $\Gamma := \mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z} \tau$ be a lattice.
Then  \begin{align*} \zeta_\Gamma(z+1) - \zeta_\Gamma(z) \end{align*} is a function independent from $z$. Why is that so?

The function is defined as follows
\begin{align}
\zeta_\Gamma(z) = \frac{1}{z} + \sum_{(m,n)\neq (0,0)} \frac{1}{z - (m\tau+n)} + \frac{1}{m\tau+n} + \frac{z}{(m\tau+n)^2}
\end{align}

I see how the middle term of the sum cancels in this substraction but i dont really see how the $z$ vanish, especially the $\frac{1}{z+1} - \frac{1}{z}$ in front of the sum. 
\begin{align*}
\zeta_\Gamma(z+1)- \zeta_\Gamma(z+1) &= \frac{1}{z+1} + \sum_{(m,n+1)\neq (0,0)} \frac{1}{(z+1) - (m\tau+n)} + \frac{1}{m\tau+n} + \frac{(z+1)}{(m\tau+n)^2} \\ &-\left( \frac{1}{z} + \sum_{(m,n)\neq (0,0)} \frac{1}{z - (m\tau+n)} + \frac{1}{m\tau+n} + \frac{z}{(m\tau+n)^2} \right) \\ &= \left(\frac{1}{z+1} - \frac{1}{z}\right) \\&+ \left( \sum_{(m,n+1)\neq (0,0)}\frac{1}{(z+1) - (m\tau+n)} + \frac{(z+1)}{(m\tau+n)^2} - \sum_{(m,n)\neq 0}\frac{1}{z - (m\tau+n)} + \frac{z}{(m\tau+n)^2}  \right)
\end{align*}
Do we need some index shifting here? I am totally clueless so any help is appreciated.

Comment: And for the connection to the Eisenstein series $E_2(\tau)$ see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3132712/276986

Comment: @reuns i have a question to that. Where are $\frac{1}{z}$ and $\frac{1}{z+1}$ in that definition of your $\zeta(z)$ ?

Comment: The term $c=0,d=0$ in $\zeta_\tau(z) =\sum_c\sum_d\frac{1}{z-c\tau-d}+1_{(c,d)\ne (0,0)}(\frac{1}{c\tau+d}+\frac{z }{(c\tau+d)^2})$. The series for $\zeta_\tau$ converges absolutely but the one for $G_2(\tau)=\sum_c\sum_d\frac{1_{(c,d)\ne (0,0)}}{(c\tau+d)^2}=\zeta_\tau(z+1)-\zeta_\tau(z)$ doesn't, so keep the order of summation I used.

Comment: Indeed i have overlooked it. Thank you for explaining

Comment: @reuns I got a last question though since im still confused a bit. In the step where you determine $\zeta_\tau(z+1)-\zeta_\tau(z)-G_2(\tau)$, the first term of $\zeta_\tau(z)$ and the first term of $\zeta_\tau(z+1)$ are missing because they cancel out? I dont really see how 
$$\sum_c\sum_d\frac{1}{z+1-c\tau-d} - \sum_c\sum_{d+1}\frac{1}{z-c\tau-d-1}$$
cancel each other out. If i shift $d \mapsto d+2$ in the first sum
$$\sum_c\sum_{d+2}\frac{1}{z-c\tau-d-1} - \sum_c\sum_{d+1}\frac{1}{z-c\tau-d-1}$$
wouldnt i have a term left?

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I see they run from infinity and thats why they cancel each other out... Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its derivative is $-\wp_\Gamma(z+1)+\wp_\Gamma(z)=0$, as $1\in\Gamma$ 
and $\Gamma$ is the
period lattice of $\wp_\Gamma$.